# Fetch all documents from mongo shard chunk

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a 3-shard collection with over 65k chunks. How can I fetch documents from this collection that reside in particular chunk, having in mind that my shard key is a hashed index?
For example, one of my chunks (a document from `chunks` collection) looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : "foo.bar-x_1947951600265057904",
"lastmod" : Timestamp(1, 0),
"lastmodEpoch" : ObjectId("57910236c0b70d5ea7025479"),
"ns" : "foo.bar",
"min" : {
    "x" : NumberLong("123") <-- this is a hashed value of a string field `x`
},
"max" : {
    "x" : NumberLong("987") <-- this is a hashed value of a string field `x`
},
"shard" : "shard0000"
}
```

How to query `foo.bar` collection by `min/max` `x` which is a regular string? I tried:

```
db.bar.find({x:{$gte: NumberLong('123'), $lte: NumberLong('987')}}).count()
```

but it returns `0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the subdocument properly, i.e. by typing `min.x` and `max.x`. Also, you have to bind the conditions by using `$and`, because they are now separate conditions. I entered the following query and it worked:

```
db.bar.find({
    $and:[
        'min.x': {
            $gte: NumberLong('123')
        }, 
        'max.x': {
            $lte: NumberLong('987')
        }
    ]
}).count()
```

Your initial query returned 0 because there is no document entry that matches `x`.

Note, that i did **not** use any sharded collections. I simply created a new collection and inserted the example you gave.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't get what I meant. The provided example document was from `config` database, `chunks` collection, created automatically by `mongos` instances. These documents provide a description of chunks spread across the sharded cluster. The actual documents have only `x` field.

Comment: So `x` is a string in the original document and in the `chunks` collection it's hashed? Then why are you comparing the hashed value to the string value?

Also, did you switch dbs from `config` to `foo`?

Comment: Because I need a range of values between those two hashes, imagine my string `a` is `foo` and `b` is `bar`. Hashes of those strings lay in the `chunks` collection, I do not know they string values (it is a hash after all), I need to query `bar` collection by their hashes not real string values

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this problem, anything you could find would help, thanks